# Define Number of documents retrieved from Firestore in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am dev my app and I retriving data from my Documents collection in firestore.
Each time an user add via the form field, a list will be built but what to use as itemCount? at the moment I just put 3 but I want each time generate another list
this is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data please Wait');
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 350,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 3,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                    elevation: 15,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Card(
                            color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                            child: Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.local_shipping,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 25,
                                )),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data['phone'],.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving documents from firestore, then inside the `itemCount`, you need to use the following:

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
```

`documents` property will return the list of documents inside the collection and `length` will give you the number of objects in this list.

Comment: I did that but I get this error:
Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: documents

Comment: If it's a DocumentSnapshot it means you are retrieving one document

Comment: so how to get the right number of documents created by the user? without error?